How to enter userid/password for Android Auto app
I have made an Android Auto app for myself which logs on to and monitors a server and shows notifications on the car head unit based on data from the server while I am driving. It works nicely but I have hard coded my userid and password for the server. I would like to make it possible to enter these on the phone, as an extension to the AA app or with a companion app. How? Any ideas, anyone? Any sample code?

You can use sign-in-template(above api level 2) provide by google
 override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        // Define the InputCallback
        val inputCallback = object : InputCallback {
            override fun onInputSubmitted(inputText: String) {
                // Handle the input submission, e.g., validation or navigation
                if (inputText.isNotEmpty()) {
                    // Send the email to the phone app
                } else {
                    // Show an error message
                     CarToast.makeText(carContext, "Please enter a valid email", CarToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        // Create the InputSignInMethod
        val inputSignInMethod = InputSignInMethod.Builder(inputCallback)
            .setHint("Enter your email") // Hint for the input field
            .setKeyboardType(InputSignInMethod.KEYBOARD_EMAIL) // Keyboard optimized for email
            .setShowKeyboardByDefault(true) // Show keyboard by default
            .build()

        // Create the SignInTemplate with the input method
        val signInTemplate = SignInTemplate.Builder(inputSignInMethod)
            .setHeaderAction(Action.APP_ICON) // Set the header action to the app icon
            .setTitle("Sign In") // Title for the sign-in screen
            .build()

        return signInTemplate
    }

more details
https://developers.google.com/cars/design/create-apps/apps-for-drivers/templates/sign-in-template

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
